# SameSite Flag against CSRF

Tags: security, web, cookies, csrf, samesite

I was wondering if the SameSite flag on the session cookie was enough of a protection against CSRF attacks.
I see CSRF token solution everywhere, but I am not sure about the need to use a CSRF token if the cookie used for authentication is already protected by the SameSite flag (in Strict mode).
On top of that, if I understood it well, tho cookie would still be sent along with subdomain URLs like `api.myapp.com` which would be perfect for my needs.

Comment: Have you considered login CSRF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat opinionated, or at least depends on your target audience and risk appetite.

`SameSite=strict` is supported in *almost* all fairly recent browsers as seen [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=samesite), but note the exception of IE11. Not many people use IE11 anymore, but for them it will not be good enough. Only you can answer whether that's good enough for your usecase, as of writing this, a significant amount of users would not be protected.

Also the general consensus seems to be that SameSite should only be used as defense in depth (eg. [here](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf/samesite-cookies) or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234386/do-i-still-need-csrf-protection-when-samesite-is-set-to-lax) in a similar question), but most of the concern is around `Lax`, and less about `Strict`. However, `Strict` is very user-unfriendly, in a real-world application you probably can't really use `Strict`, because that's very bad UX.

The usual arguments are around browser support (as above), GET requests changing state (only relevant to `Lax`), and some special cases still revolving around GET changing state.

So my take currently is that the reason `SameSite=Strict` is not good enough in general is the lack of full browser support (IE11), and a strong point against it is bad user experience. I can imagine circumstances where it is good enough. `SameSite=Lax` I think is only a defense in depth measure, because of the issues above, which probably don't affect your application now, but might in the future, and nobody will remember to think about `SameSite` settings.

Comment: Why would Strict be that bad of an UX?

Comment: If you follow a link from somewhere else to a site where you are already logged in, you expect to still be logged in, having to log in again is weird. Also I usually tell people it's a potential sign of phishing, and deliberately working like that kind of undermines that awareness. This all might be acceptable in some cases though, I'm not at all saying this is wrong - it just might be unusual.

Comment: ok I see now, I will definitely set it to Lax

Comment: I feel like your statement that "Strict is very user-unfriendly" stems from a misunderstanding. Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @jub0bs I described it in my comment above. Don't get me wrong though, I'm all for `Strict` if business requirements allow that. It's just in my experience, many times they don't. :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/aUF2QCEudPo helped me to further understand the samesite flag

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer from Gabor which explains the problem well. There is a way to solve this though, if you set up your code like an SPA, to work like this:

- Requests for web content (such as navigation) do not require a cookie
- The SameSite=strict cookie is only used in Ajax requests to get data

**HOW IT WORKS**

- If your web app runs at https://mywebapp.com
- Then issue the secure cookie as the result of calling an API at https://api.mywebapp.com
- The cookie has a domain of **.mywebapp.com** and is SameSite + Cross Origin

**OAUTH**

For an OAuth back end for front end solution you would do this:

- Host the API at https://api.mywebapp.com
- When the web app receives an OAuth response, it sends the Authorization Code to the API
- The API processes it, then issues a strongly encrypted cookie containing tokens